# Grant select on all tables does not work on continuous aggregates in Timescaledb

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, continuous-aggregates

I have a read-only user which has been granted `select on all tables` including default privileges for any future schema additions.

I have a Continuous Aggregate on a TimescaleDB Hypertable. The read-only user can query the hypertable fine, but when they attempt to make a query on the continuous aggregate they get the following error:

`ERROR:  permission denied for table _materialized_hypertable_4`

Is there any special permission or additional configuration I need to add for this user to be able to query Continuous Aggregate materialized views?

I am running Postgres 13.2 with TimescaleDB 2.1.0.

Comment: Thanks for this @jbx 
On first look that seems like a bug but I will see if I can find out more (Timescale's community manager...)

Comment: @greenweeds thanks. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Looks like you might need to update TimescaleDB see these release notes... GRANT only available from 2.5.1 https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md/